# Tensorflow, maintain a history of cost function for training

Tags: python, tensorflow

My objective is to train a neural network using the history of cost function. For example,

Loss = sum_{k=T}^{20} ||f_{k} - f_{k-1}||

where T is the current iteration of training and ||.|| is the usual L2 norm. My current attempt involves maintaining a placeholder for returning the costs to the main loop, but this way, I cannot use tf.gradients from tensorflow.

I am not sure how to implement this in tensorflow with python because I want to use auto-differentiation tools in tensorflow for training the weights. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Do your training iterations have a sequential relationship with one another, like in a recurrent network? If so, you should use that type of model explicitly and evaluate a loss function on a sequence of output. If not, then this seems strictly worse than standard momentum-based optimization methods, which update gradients in a way that takes into account previously computed gradients from previous examples. Your method would arbitrarily bundle groups of training instances for purposes of the loss. Perhaps you can elaborate on why that is appropriate in your model?

Comment: For example, merely re-shuffling your training data would cause the calculated loss to completely change for any given single input. This doesn't generally make sense, for the loss connected to a single example to be a function of where that example happens to fall in the data set, unless there is some direct sequential relationship that induces a specific order of the training input, in which case an RNN that produces sequence-valued output would be more appropriate. (Note I'm not talking about the gradient estimate across a batch, rather just on a single training example).

Comment: The model I am working on is an interconnected multi-agent system where only one agent get the training input and the rest of the agents train according to the change in the states of their neighbors. The change in the state is represented by [f(k) - f(k-1)] and the average is to normalize the change. So the loss we are talking about is not dependent on the data-input per say but depends on the internal states of the model when the data input is fixed.

Comment: Is your loss based on a fixed or variable number of previous steps? It seems like you're going to need to implement this using a `tf.while_loop` to loop over the various iterations within a single call to `sess.run`

Comment: Its based on a fixed number of previous steps. I will check on tf.while_loop and get back to you.